# Does ffmpeg support drop and non-drop frames?

Tags: ffmpeg, decode, video-processing, decoder, transcoding

I am implementing a simple video player using ffmpeg. After so much of googling, I couldn't find ans for my question. Here it is:

Does ffmpeg supports drop and non-drop timecodes. If yes, Can anyone help me in enabling it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It does support it. Do you want it printed or embedded in the file. Or just played back at that rate?

Comment: thnq Mulvya. I am expecting the decoded frame timestamps in drop and non-drop frame timecode format. How to extract it from ffmpeg. ?? And is there any flag to know wheather current video is drop or non-drop video?? Thank you for your time.

Comment: If fps of the video is 23.976 or 24000/1001  or 29.97 or 30000/1001, then it's drop frame. Which variable are you reading to derive timecode? PTS?

Comment: I am using av_frame_get_best_effort_timestamp API to extract timestamp of decoded video.

Comment: You will have to wait till someone familiar with the API comes along, but till then see if these headers [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/timecode.h) help.